# Where can I get VS code snippets?

Tags: visual-studio, code-snippets

Apparently there are many questions that deal with how to store code snippets for Visual Studio, but I did not find one that contains links. So, is there a website that offers useful snippets? My google-fu only brought up many false positives or broken sites.